# Constructing non-reduced schemes from reduced

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be projective scheme, $X \subset Y$, $X$ is reduced and $Y$ is not reduced. Since these are projective schemes, $Y$ and $X$ are of the form $\mathrm{Proj}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Proj}(A/I)$, respectively for some ring $A$ and ideal $I$ of $A$. Does there exist an ideal $J$ of $A$ such that $X':=\mathrm{Proj}(A/J)$
is non-reduced and the associated reduced scheme $X'_{red}=X$?

Comment: You probably mean graded ring/ideal. And I think $J= I^n$ works.